# Member functions that are sometimes const

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class design similar to the following:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    bool IsValid() const;
    void MakeValid();
private:
    bool CheckValidity(bool fix);
};

bool MyClass::IsValid() const {
    // Check validity, but don't fix any problems found.  Doesn't work.
    return CheckValidity(false);
}

void MyClass::MakeValid() {
    // Check validity and fix problems found.
    CheckValidity(true);
}
```

`IsValid` should be `const`, because it doesn't make changes. `MakeValid` should be non-const, because it does make changes. They share the same implementation, `CheckValidity`, but because `CheckValidity` may or may not make changes, it can't be marked `const`.

What's the best way to handle this? The simplest approach is to just use `const_cast`, but casting away const feels a bit dirty:

```
bool MyClass::IsValid() const {
    // Check validity, but don't fix any problems found.
    return const_cast<MyClass*>(this)->CheckValidity(false);
}
```

Is this a legitimate use of `const_cast`? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Split checks and "fixing" into two different functions? Checks is `const` and fix is not?

Comment: I agree with @crashmstr, having one function which does two different things is a bad design smell.

Comment: Actually, already the name `CheckValidity` suggests that this function only does a check and can be const. If you want to `MakeValid` it is something different (and it shouldnt be const...)

Comment: @crashmstr - Ideally, I'd agree, but checking for problems is complicated (looping over nested sub-structures and checking them for consistency against each other), and fixing problems once they're found is very simple (3 lines of code), and and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to cleanly separate these without duplicating or excessively complicating the code. (I.e., any solutions that I can think of to address this are far more complicated than a single `const_cast` and boolean parameter.)

Comment: If you modify an object that was declared const by using `const_cast` the result is undefined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming your implementation looks similar to this:

```
bool CheckValidity(bool fix)
{
    // Actually check validity.
    bool isValid = ...;

    if (!isValid && fix)
    {
        // Attempt to fix validity (and update isValid).
        isValid = ...;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

You really have two different functions shoved into one. One of the key indicators of this kind of entanglement is the boolean argument to the function... which smells because the caller cannot immediately discern whether to put true or false without referencing code/docs.

Split up the method:

```
bool CheckValidity() const
{
    // Actually check validity.
    bool isValid = ...;
    return isValid;
}

void FixValidity()
{
    // Attempt to fix validity.
    // ...
}
```

And then your public methods can make the calls more appropriately.

```
bool IsValid() const
{
    // No problem: const method calling const method
    return CheckValidity();
}

void MakeValid()
{
    if (!CheckValidity())  // No problem: non-const calling const
    {
         FixValidity();    // No problem: non-const calling non-const
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the checking logic is complicated (looping over nested sub-structures and checking them for consistency against each other), and fixing problems requires knowing which sub-elements have problems, so I'm struggling to find a clean way to separate `CheckValidity` and `FixValidity` without duplicating or significantly complicating the logic.

Comment: @JoshKelley It may be that you can separate out traversal from checking from manipulation. Or you may be finding Check vs Fix difficult to separate because your existing code/structures are complected.

One "easy" way to split into Check and Fix is simply to duplicate your current CheckValidity(bool) method. With the first, assume bool is false everywhere in that method, strip out dead code, then remove the bool parameter. With the second, rename to FixValidity, assume bool is true, strip out dead code, then remove bool parameter. Then see what is still common between the two and refactor.

Comment: Thinking about it further, splitting traversal seems to be the way to go. Thank you.

Comment: Another way might be to make `CheckValidity` return an iterator or a pointer or an ID or any information necessary to call `FixValidity` instead of a bool. then in your public method checks whether `CheckValidity` return a null value (or any value you would use as a replacement of true) and act accordingly. This way you might not need to traverse the whole tree again when you fix.

Comment: To coin a phrase: "Do, or do not.  There is no try.".   A method is or is not const, there is no maybe.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach that might be useful in some cases.  It might be overkill for your particular situation.

Your CheckValidity function could be passed a handler object.  The CheckValidity function would find what was not valid, and call an appropriate method of the handler object. You could have many different methods for different kinds of validity violations, and those methods could be passed enough information that the problem could be fixed if necessary. To implement IsValid, you just need to pass a handler which sets a flag indicating there was a problem. To implement MakeValid, you can pass a handler which actually fixes the problem. The const issue is addressed by having the fixing handler keep a non-const reference to the object.

Here is an example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    bool IsValid() const 
    { 
        bool flag = false;
        CheckValidity(FlagProblems{flag});
        return flag;
    }

    void MakeValid() 
    {
        CheckValidity(FixProblems{*this});
    }

private:
    struct FlagProblems {
        bool& flag;

        void handleType1(arg1,arg2)      const { flag = true; }
        void handleType2(arg1,arg2,arg3) const { flag = true; }
        .
        .
        .
    };

    struct FixProblems {
        MyClass& object;
        void handleType1(arg1,arg2)      const { ... }
        void handleType2(arg1,arg2,arg3) const { ... }
        .
        .
        .
    };

    template <typename Handler>
    bool CheckValidity(const Handler &handler) const
    {
        // for each possible problem:
        //   if it is a type-1 problem:
        //     handler.handleType1(arg1,arg2);
        //   if it is a type-2 problem:
        //     handler.handleType2(arg1,arg2,arg3);
        //   .
        //   .
        //   .
    }
};
```

Using the template allows for maximum efficiency. Alternatively, using a base class with virtual functions for the handler might provide a smaller executable size.

If the ways in which the object can be invalid are simpler, then having CheckValidity return a struct containing the relevant information may be more straightforward.

Comment: Definitely a valid possibility, though with that kind of separation, `CheckValidity` might be more appropriately named `Traverse` or something similar indicating that it is moving through the data and applying handlers rather than doing any checking of its own.

Comment: @MatthewMoss: I really meant that we are going though each possible problem, rather than each possible object in the data structure. I'll reword it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template specialization to separate the parts that only have purpose on a non-const object.

Following is an implementation for a toy class. It has a single c-array member v with 10 ints, and, for our purposes, it is only valid when every single one of them equals to zero.

```
class ten_zeroes {
  int v[10];
  void fix(int pos) {v[pos] = 0;}

  public:
  ten_zeroes() { // construct as invalid object
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      v[i] = i;
    }
  }
};
```

See that I already made a function member that fixes an invalid position, and a nice constructor that initializes it as an invalid object(don't do that :D)

Since we are going to use templates, we need to move the implementation of the check/fix cycle outside of the class. In order for the relevant functions to be able to access `v` and the `fix()` method, we'll make them friends. Our code now looks like:

```
class ten_zeroes {
  int v[10];
  void fix(int pos) {v[pos] = 0;}

  public:
  ten_zeroes() { // construct as invalid object
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      v[i] = i;
    }
  }

  template<typename T>
  friend void fix(T& obj, int pos);

  template<typename T>
  friend bool check(T& obj);
};
```

`check()`'s implementation is straightforward:

```
// Check and maybe fix object
template<typename T>
bool check(T& obj){
  bool result = true;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (obj.v[i]) {
      result = false;
      fix(obj, i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now here is the tricky part. We want our `fix()` function to change behaviour based on constness. For that we'll need to specialize the template. For a non-const object, it will fix the position. For a const one, it will do nothing:

```
// For a regular object, fix the position
template<typename T>
void fix(T& obj, int pos) { obj.fix(pos);}

// For a const object, do nothing
template<typename T>
void fix(const T& obj, int pos) {}
```

Finally, we write our `is_valid()` and `make_valid()` methods, and here we have the full implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

class ten_zeroes {
  int v[10];
  void fix(int pos) {v[pos] = 0;}

  public:
  ten_zeroes() { // construct as invalid object
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      v[i] = i;
    }
  }

  bool is_valid() const {return check(*this);} // since this is const, it will run check with a const ten_zeroes object
  void make_valid() { check(*this);} // since this is non-const , it run check with a non-const ten_zeroes object

  template<typename T>
  friend void fix(T& obj, int pos);

  template<typename T>
  friend bool check(T& obj);
};

// For a regular object, fix the position
template<typename T>
void fix(T& obj, int pos) { obj.fix(pos);}

// For a const object, do nothing
template<typename T>
void fix(const T& obj, int pos) {}

// Check and maybe fix object
template<typename T>
bool check(T& obj){
  bool result = true;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (obj.v[i]) {
      result = false;
      fix(obj, i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main(){
  ten_zeroes a;
  std::cout << a.is_valid() << a.is_valid(); // twice to make sure the first one didn't make any changes
  a.make_valid(); // fix the object
  std::cout << a.is_valid() << std::endl; // check again
}
```

I hope you don't mind the `main()` function there. It will test our little toy, and output `001`, as expected. Now any maintenance on this code will not have to deal with code duplication, what you probably was intending to avoid. I hope this was helpful.

Of course, if you intend to hide these implementation details from the final user, you should move them to an appropriate detail namespace. I'll leave that up to you :)